Animated series about a tribe searching for a utopia with a kid who is different from the rest of them
I mostly remember the story had to do with these people who are some sort of tribe and travel around. There is this kid who is different from all the rest of them, because while they have blue finger, but like without bones, tops to their heads, his are red. It is not only that which makes him special; he is also, I think, the key to finding this utopia of sorts. All the while, they are being followed by this evil group of travellers who also want to find this utopia.

In roughly which year did you watch this? And was the animation hand-drawn (2D) or computer-generated (3D)?

Is this Legend of Enyo (2009–2010)...?
From the show's opening narration:

In a faraway world, the nomadic Doodjie tribe found an orphan boy. They named him Enyo. As he grew, so too did his unique powers. It is Enyo's destiny to lead his tribe to the Hidden Valley. They must overcome great dangers to reach it... some more deadly than others. This is the Legend of Enyo.

It's a 3D-animated series set on a planet populated by various tribes of humanoids who have tentacle-like protrusions growing out of their scalps, instead of hair. The colour of these protrusions varies from one tribe to another.
The main character, Enyo, is a young member of the Doodjie tribe, who have blue protrusions on their heads. They found him abandoned in a basket with an amulet when he was a baby and adopted him. Since he's descended from another tribe, the protrusions on his head are coloured orange.


Legend of Enyo (2009–2010)

In the first episode, the terrain frequented by the Doodjie is becoming increasingly barren and inhospitable. The Doodjie's shaman, Shamani, believes Enyo's amulet is the key to accessing the legendary Hidden Valley, a "place of abundance with food enough for all," but the Doodjie are stalked by the Raiders, a nefarious tribe who want the Hidden Valley for themselves.
As the story progresses, Enyo gains magical powers linked to his amulet and is taught the ways of the shaman by Shamani.




The video is not available for me - not sure if it's a region based restriction

@fez - Thanks for the heads-up. I've replaced the video with a different one; let me know if the new one works for you. In case it doesn't, I've added a still image as well.

The new link works :)
